# TokenSwap createInitSwapInstruction, where can I find "Account" variable?

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, swap

```
    import {
  PublicKey,
  Keypair,
  Transaction,
  Connection,
  SystemProgram,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import {
  TokenSwap,
  TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID,
  TokenSwapLayout,
  CurveType,
} from "@solana/spl-token-swap";
import createAccount from "../createAccountToken";
import createTokenFunction from "../createTokenFunction";
import GetAccount from "../getAssociatedTokenAddress";
import { tokenAccountPool, tokenSwapStateAccount } from "../../utils/constants";
import { getAccount, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID } from "@solana/spl-token";

const createSwap = async (
  connection: Connection,
  payer: PublicKey,
  tokenA: PublicKey,
  tokenB: PublicKey
) => {
  // number 1 -> create account that cointain information on swap
  const transaction = new Transaction();
  const tokenSwapAccount = Keypair.generate();
  const rent = await TokenSwap.getMinBalanceRentForExemptTokenSwap(connection);

  const tokenSwapStateAccountInstruction = await SystemProgram.createAccount({
    newAccountPubkey: tokenSwapAccount.publicKey,
    fromPubkey: payer,
    lamports: rent,
    space: TokenSwapLayout.span,
    programId: TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID,
  });

  transaction.add(tokenSwapStateAccountInstruction);

  /// ==================================

  // number 2 -> find PDA

  const [swapAuthority, bump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
    [tokenSwapAccount.publicKey.toBuffer()],

    TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID
  );

  // number 3 -> create token accounts for Token A and Token B

  const tokenAAccount = await createAccount(swapAuthority, tokenA, true);
  const tokenBAccount = await createAccount(swapAuthority, tokenB, true);

  transaction.add(tokenAAccount, tokenBAccount);

  // number 4 -> create token that rappresenting receipt of deposit (LP token)
  const { transaction: poolTokenMintTX, mintAccountKeypair: poolTokenMint } =
    await createTokenFunction(
      "non serve",
      connection,
      payer,
      swapAuthority,
      null,
      2
    );

  transaction.add(poolTokenMintTX);

  // number 5 -> create Account that contain miter token before send to user
  const accountPoolTokenMint = await createAccount(
    payer,
    poolTokenMint.publicKey
  );

  transaction.add(accountPoolTokenMint);

  // number 6 -> create Pool Token Fee Account (in this case is a specific serum account (still serum  in this moment? ????))

  const feeOwner = new PublicKey(
    "HfoTxFR1Tm6kGmWgYWD6J7YHVy1UwqSULUGVLXkJqaKN"
  );

  const poolTokenFeeAccount = await createAccount(
    feeOwner,
    poolTokenMint.publicKey
  );

  transaction.add(poolTokenFeeAccount);

  //const _tokenSwapAccount = await getAccount(connection,poolTokenMint.publicKey)

  const poolAccountTokenA = await GetAccount(connection, swapAuthority, tokenA);

  const poolAccountTokenB = await GetAccount(connection, swapAuthority, tokenB);

  const accountFeeOwner = await GetAccount(
    connection,
    feeOwner,
    poolTokenMint.publicKey
  );
  if (!poolAccountTokenA || !poolAccountTokenB || !accountFeeOwner) {
    return;
  }
  const createSwapInstruction = TokenSwap.createInitSwapInstruction(
    tokenSwapAccount.publicKey, **** error *******
    swapAuthority,
    poolAccountTokenA,
    poolAccountTokenB,
    poolTokenMint.publicKey,
    accountFeeOwner,
    poolTokenMint.publicKey,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Program ID
    TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Swap Program ID
    0, // Trade fee numerator
    10000, // Trade fee denominator
    5, // Owner trade fee numerator
    10000, // Owner trade fee denominator
    0, // Owner withdraw fee numerator
    0, // Owner withdraw fee denominator
    20, // Host fee numerator
    100, // Host fee denominator
    CurveType.ConstantProduct // Curve type
  );

  transaction.add(createSwapInstruction);

  return transaction;
};

export default createSwap;
```

ERROR _
L'argomento di tipo 'PublicKey' non è assegnabile al parametro di tipo 'Account'.
Nel tipo 'PublicKey' mancano le proprietà seguenti del tipo 'Account':  publicKey,secretKey

translate

The argument of type 'PublicKey' is not assignable to the parameter of type 'Account'. Type 'PublicKey' is missing the following properties of type 'Account': publicKey,secretKey

Comment: Can you add the line that's triggering the error? It should be a pretty easy fix after that, since you're just passing in a `PublicKey` instead of an `Account` somewhere

Comment: this line take me the error : <<  tokenSwapAccount.publicKey, **** error *******>>
In tutorial pass one publicKey , but in my code require Account.

Answer (score 1):

Ah great, thanks for the extra info! You need to change this to:

```
const createSwapInstruction = TokenSwap.createInitSwapInstruction(
    tokenSwapAccount,
    swapAuthority,
    poolAccountTokenA,
    poolAccountTokenB,
    poolTokenMint.publicKey,
    accountFeeOwner,
    poolTokenMint.publicKey,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Program ID
    TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Swap Program ID
    0, // Trade fee numerator
    10000, // Trade fee denominator
    5, // Owner trade fee numerator
    10000, // Owner trade fee denominator
    0, // Owner withdraw fee numerator
    0, // Owner withdraw fee denominator
    20, // Host fee numerator
    100, // Host fee denominator
    CurveType.ConstantProduct // Curve type
  );
```

Since `createInitSwapInstruction` takes an `Account` for the first parameter, not a `PublicKey`